# String array list using regex for a numbers in it

Tags: java, regex, string, wildcard

I want to select items from string array which contains as follows

http://www.ijk.com/123321/1/page.com

http://www.ijk.com/123321/2/page.com

http://www.ijk.com/123321/3/page.com

http://www.ijk.com/123321/page.com

Condition is as items contains = 123321/*/page.com - * could be any number

Please help.

Comment: You want to extract the item from urls? such as 1,2,3?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you have a list of items and you want to match the items that fulfill the condition `123321/*/page.com`. From your example data that would mean that the last one should not match.

If that is the case, you could use `\d+` where you state that "* could be any number".

[`http://www\.ijk\.com/123321/\d+/page\.com`](https://regex101.com/r/FIVugD/1)